# PHP remove first zero from decimals without round off

Tags: php

How to remove the first zero in a decimal number without round off.
whenever a function detect the first zero in decimal stop it and remove the zero and excess decimals.

I tried this:

```
$number = 1.063;
echo floor_dec($number,$deg);

    function floor_dec($number, $deg = null)
    {
        if ($deg == null)
            return $number * 1000 / 1000;
        else
            return $number * pow(10, $deg) / pow(10, $deg);
    }
```

Desired output:

```
1.063 -> output 1
1.30720-> output 1.3
1.3072-> output  1.3
1.823070  -> output 1.823
```

Comment: Not sure what `$deg` means or what `floor_dec` is trying to do but `a * b / b`  equals `a` because multiplication and division are opposite operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tricky one  using [strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```php
function removeFirstZeroToEnd($number)
{
    $str = explode('.',$number);
    if(isset($str[1])){
        // find first zero after decimal
        $num = substr($str[1],0, strpos($str[1], "0"));
        // adding zero will convert it to number
        $number = ($str[0].'.'.$num) + 0;
    }
    return $number;
}
```

Comment: Well if you're going for a solution like this, may as well simplify it more and explode `$str[1]` at '0' and just use `$str[1][0]` instead of `substr` `strpos` stuff

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this would be a lot easier by just treating it as a string and then just get the desired substring and then convert back to float:

```
floatval(rtrim(substr($number, 0, strpos($number, 0)), "."));
```

Comment: This will return float value  while `$number` is  integer. Need to check integer for then. for example 1 will return 1.0

Comment: He asked "How to remove the first zero in a decimal number" but sure, it won't work for non-decimal numbers

Answer (score 0):

**Obligatory regex solution:**

```
$numbers = [
    123,
    1.063,
    1.30720,
    1.3072,
    1.823070
];
foreach ($numbers as &$n) {
    $n = preg_replace ('~^([0-9]+(\.[1-9]+)?).*~','$1',$n);
}
print_r($numbers);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1.3
    [3] => 1.3
    [4] => 1.823
)
```